# GnuCobol - How to reset read without reopen?

Tags: performance, file, readfile, sequential, gnucobol

I started study (again) Cobol, And I found GnuCobol as compiler possibility to use at my Linux box.

So, my problem consist at read a sequential file from beginning without reopen, because it is into a procedure. If I reopen, all work is lost :-(.

If someone knows how to do it, please help me.

I read all GnuCobol documentation, but I nothing found.

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to read from a file which you've wrote to which is still open for writing? Note: the OS may not have flushed that to disk...

But you likely want to `CLOSE`, `OPEN-INPUT`, `READ`, `OPEN EXTEND`.

Comment: Indeed, I want perform a key search from 1st record without CLOSE/OPEN statements. They consume a lot of time.

Comment: It sounds like you'd be better using `ORGANIZATION INDEXED` (ISAM) which allows both sequential and direct reads and writes at any time, opening it with `OPEN INPUT-OUTPUT`.

Comment: What do you think of posting whatever worked for you as answer?